# Consulta Llama muchos Campos

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, subconsultas

tengo un problema con esta consulta.

Necesito llamar los campos de una tabla la cual se llama usuario_rol y otra tabla llamada roles estoy ejecutando esta consulta:

```
SELECT i.id_usuario , a.accion  FROM roles a  join usuario_rol i WHERE i.id_usuario = '16'
```

al ejecutarla me llama todos estos campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que esta haciendo es llamar la cantidad de acciones osea 23 la misma accion, es decir abajo tambien se repiten las otras acciones 23 veces y asi hasta que llegue a la ultima accion que tiene ese id_usuario

lo que necesito es que me llame una sola ves cada accion que tiene id_usuario. tq

Comment: si la estructura y un ejemplo de los datos que consultas poco podemos hacer ... solo que agregues un limite en la consulta...

Comment: Intenta agrupar, algo así: **`SELECT i.id_usuario , a.accion  FROM roles a  join usuario_rol i WHERE i.id_usuario = '16'  GROUP BY i.id_usuario , a.accion`**

Comment: lo siento pero lo único que vas a lograr es que se cierren tus preguntas y de continuar así o eliminándolas, el mismo sistema te va a limitar ha hacer nuevas preguntas... estamos tratando de apoyarte para que aprendas como usar este sitio de manera correcta ... puedes leer esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: gracias pero las preguntas son muy diferentes porque la solución que dieron en el otro post esta bien pero ahora estoy buscando en hacer otra cosa, mejor tomar el tiempo para leer y así opinar

Answer (score 1):

> lo que necesito es que me llame una sola ve<s>`s`</s>**z** cada accion que tiene
> id_usuario.

Para eso necesitas usar **[`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)**.

Algo así:

```
SELECT 
    i.id_usuario, 
    a.accion  
FROM roles AS a  
    LEFT JOIN usuario_rol AS i ON a.id_rol=i.usuario_rol
WHERE i.id_usuario = '16'  
GROUP BY 
    i.id_usuario, a.accion;
```

Esta consulta agrupará los resultados por cada valor de `id_usuario` y `acción`.

Para más detalles consulta este [tutorial sobre `GROUP BY`](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group-by.aspx).

Aquí te dejo un fiadle de prueba, la **Query #1** es el resultado que esperas, las otras son para verificar los datos de prueba insertados:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
 CREATE TABLE roles 
 (     
   id_rol INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,     
   accion VARCHAR(50) 
 );   
 
 CREATE TABLE usuario_rol 
 (     
   id_usuario INT NOT NULL,     
   usuario_rol INT NOT NULL 
 );

INSERT INTO roles (accion) VALUES 
('Cotizaciones'), ('Respuestas Rápidas');


INSERT INTO usuario_rol (id_usuario,usuario_rol) 
VALUES 
(1,1), 
(1,2),
(1,2),
(1,1), 
(16,1), 
(16,2),
(16,2),
(16,1), 
(16,1), 
(16,2),
(1,1)
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    i.id_usuario, 
    a.accion  
FROM roles AS a  
    LEFT JOIN usuario_rol AS i ON a.id_rol=i.usuario_rol
WHERE i.id_usuario = '16'  
GROUP BY 
    i.id_usuario, a.accion;
```

| id_usuario | accion |
| --- | --- |
| 16 | Cotizaciones |
| 16 | Respuestas Rápidas |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT * FROM roles;
```

| id_rol | accion |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cotizaciones |
| 2 | Respuestas Rápidas |

---

**Query #3**

```
SELECT * FROM usuario_rol;
```

| id_usuario | usuario_rol |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 16 | 1 |
| 16 | 2 |
| 16 | 2 |
| 16 | 1 |
| 16 | 1 |
| 16 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rwSVraPcN737n6DJdTNN3W/0)

Comment: gracias, ahora me trae todas las acciones que existen, mas no las que tiene solo ese id_usuario

Comment: falta la condicion de join Cedano.. por eso le funciona mal

Comment: podrías por favor darme un explicación

Comment: Cierto @gbianchi, fallo mío, no me di cuenta. Ya está corregido.

Comment: @DianaBecerra faltaba la condición del `JOIN`, revisa la respuesta editada. He agregado también un fiddle para que puedas hacer pruebas y ver cómo funciona.

Comment: Para nada señor... para eso estamos todos... ;)

Comment: @DianaBecerra por favor, lee el [tour] y recuerda aceptar la respuesta que te haya funcionado y solucione tu problema...